# Django Rest Framework: Custom Views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have a django installation with currently two apps ( common / destinations ) and i want to create custom api views across these apps.

in common i have a model country

models.py app common

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Country(models.Model):
    CONTINENTS = (
        ('Europe', 'Europe'),
        ('Asia', 'Asia'),
        ('Africa', 'Africa'),
        ('northamerica', 'North America'),
        ('southamerica', 'South America'),
        ('australia', 'Australia')
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    continent = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=CONTINENTS)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.FileField()
```

models.py app destination

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Destination(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    country = models.ForeignKey("common.Country", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField()
```

serializers.py app destination

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from common.serializers import CountrySerializer
from .models import Destination 

class DestinationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

country = CountrySerializer()

class Meta:
    model = Destination
    fields = ("id", "name", "code", "country", "image")
```

views.py app destination

```
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import DestinationSerializer, ImageSerializer
from .models import Destination

# Create your views here.

class DestinationView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, code):
        destination =  Destination.objects.filter(code=code.upper())
        if destination:
            serializer = DestinationSerializer(destination, many=True)
            return Response(status=200, data=serializer.data)
        return Response(status=400, data={"Destination not found"})
```

When i make a API call /api/destination/PMI everything works. i get my destination from destination app and country from common app.

```
**GET /api/destination/**

HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Palma de Mallorca",
        "code": "PMI",
        "country": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Spain",
            "code": "ES",
            "continent": "Europe",
            "content": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "image": "http://localhost:1000/media/logo.svg"
        },
        "image": "http://localhost:1000/media/2020-08-03_07-40.png"
    }
]
```

Now i want to create a view which only returns the images from common / destination

e.g.

```
GET **/api/destination/pmi/image**
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
[
    {
         "code": "pmi",
         "destination_image" : "image.png",
         "country_image" : "country.png" 
    }
]
```

how, if possible, can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy and clean way to do that is to have an extra serializer for your view like:

```
class ExtraSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    destination_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    country_image = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Destination
        fields = (
            'code', 'destination_image', 'country_image'
        )

    def get_destination_image(self, obj):
        req = self.context['request']
        # build_absolute_uri will convert your related url to absolute url
        return req.build_absolute_uri(obj.image.url)

    def get_country_image(self, obj):
        req = self.context['request']
        return req.build_absolute_uri(obj.country.image.url)
```

Also note that you should pass the request from your view to context of your serializer to build an absolute url (Example: `ExtraSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': self.request})` or `context={'request': request}` if you're using same `APIView` as before) and then use the data of this serializer.

Comment: works ! thank you. but how can i get the filename only? with req.buuild_absolute_uri i gett the full api uri. i just need the filename

Comment: You're welcome. For returning name you just have to replace the line `req.build_absolute_uri(obj.country.image.url)` with `obj.country.image.name` in your serializer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class All_HomePage(APIView):

    def get(self,request):

        #get destination_data
        data = Destination.objects.all()
        destination_ser = DestinationSerializer(data,many=True)
        destination_data=[]
        for record in destination_ser.data:
            code = record['code']
            image = record['image']
            destination_data.append({"code":code ,"destination_image":image})


        #get country_data
        data = Country.objects.all()
        country_ser = CountrySerializer(data,many=True)
        country_data=[]
        for record in country_ser.data:
            image = record['image']
            country_data.append({"country_image":image,})


        return Response({
            "destination_data":destination_data, "country_data":country_data,
            })
```